# Indexing in c, differences between declaration and assigning

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, indexing, declaration

Since C starts counting from zero why in this case of Two-Dimensional Arrays where 2 rows and 5 columns are needed, it is not given as `grades[1][4]` but it is written as `grades[2][5]` instead?

See example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

        int main() {
        int grades[2][5]; <-------???? why not [1][4]???
        float average;
        int i;
        int j;

        grades[0][0] = 80;
        grades[0][1] = 70;
        grades[0][2] = 65;
        grades[0][3] = 89;
        grades[0][4] = 90;

        grades[1][0] = 85;
        grades[1][1] = 80;
        grades[1][2] = 80;
        grades[1][3] = 82;
        grades[1][4] = 87; <--- why not until [2][5] too????

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            average = 0;
            
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                average += grades[i][j];
            }

            average /= 5.0;
            printf("The average marks obtained in subject %d is: %.2f\n", i, average);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The declaration denotes the *magnitude* of a dimension; indexing denotes a *location* relative to the base of a dimension. They're not the same thing.

Comment: @WhozCraig: That says what the rules are but does not really answer why. There is no mathematical or technical impediment to specifying that, in the C language, the declaration would specify the last element index rather than the number of elements. Further, since K&R made declarations be a “picture” of the thing as it is used (e.g., `int *p` says `*p` will be used as an `int`), then `int a[2]` would fit this model better by saying `a[2]` will be used as an `int`, so there must be an element with index 2 in the array, than by saying `a[something]` will be used as an `int`, but the 2 is a size.

Answer (score -1):

Such a declaration

```
int grades[1][4];
```

will only confuse readers of the code.

This declaration

```
int grades[2][5];
```

explicitly says to the reader of the code how many there are rows and columns.

In this case valid ranges of indices are `[ 0, 2 )` and `[ 0, 5 )`.

In many programming languages ranges are specified such a way that the first value specifies the beginning of a range and the second value specifies a value after acceptable values in a range as `[N1, N2 )` In this case if `N1` is equal to `N2` then it means that the range is empty.